# Exception was raised when trying to close popover windows in iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, exception, crash

Sorry I have narrowed down the bug so it is not a AFNetworking issue but rather a UI issue.

I have a collection view. When I tapped the collection view a popover window would be displayed and I can choose to download something, then a progress bar would show the progress. At the mean time the collectionviewcell would also display another progress bar on itself. Then I close the window and tapped the cell again, do something and then close it. It may not raise an exception at the second time and when I open and close the popOver again the exception was raised.

Here is the bt trace from lldb:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1214fc, 0x38592626 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb1b8d8b0)
    frame #0: 0x38592626 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6
    frame #1: 0x302f7056 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
    frame #2: 0x302f6ff6 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
    frame #3: 0x302f6fd0 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
    frame #4: 0x302e2736 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
    frame #5: 0x302f6a4e UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
    frame #6: 0x302f6720 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
    frame #7: 0x302f16ea UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 758
    frame #8: 0x302c68ec UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
    frame #9: 0x302c4f96 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7102
    frame #10: 0x2da7125a CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #11: 0x2da7072a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
    frame #12: 0x2da6ef1e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 622
    frame #13: 0x2d9d9f4e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    frame #14: 0x2d9d9d32 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #15: 0x328d3662 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
    frame #16: 0x3032516c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
  * frame #17: 0x0003b12c ChinesePod`main(argc=1, argv=0x27dccd04) + 300 at main.m:39
```

I've no idea what is wrong by looking at the trace. Any idea what is wrong with my app?

EDIT:

When I enabled NSZombie, I saw this error in the console:

```
*** -[BlurViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x166e7df0
```

the BlurViewController is a viewcontroller which is responsible for showing the PopOver window. Does this mean the BlurViewController is deallocated?

Source code of dismissDialog:

```
- (void)dismissDialog
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        self.view.alpha = 0.f;
        self.popUp.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeFromParentViewController];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.popUp removeFromSuperview];
        if (!self.popUp.isDownloading) {
            _popUp = nil;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
            _blurView.alpha = 0.f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [_blurView removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: please give the code you are using to download using AFNetworking.

Comment: Some object you are referring to has been released. Please post the code for your popover display method.  You can also try running with NSZombies enabled

Comment: @Paulw11 enabling zombies in Xode will help some but using Instruments with Zombies setup is far better... can see all refcount increments and decrements and what code is responsible, a must-know for every iOS developer

Comment: @RobP, sorry, yes that is what I meant. I should have been more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day debugging I finally worked it out.

Previously I defined a `BlurViewController` instance `bvController` in my main viewController as a method variable but it seems bvController was released after I close the popOver UIView in it. I moved `bvController` to a strong property and use the following code in the method the app doesn't crash anymore.

```
MainViewController.h:

@property (strong, nonatomic)  BlurViewController *bvController;

MainViewController.m:

if (!self.bvController) {
    self.bvController = [[BlurViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Memory allocating and deallocating is really interesting in Objective-C. Coming from Java and Python background I am always scratching my head here and there.